# In my React component throws this error

Tags: react-redux

Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This 
   usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component.
   This is a no-op. Please check the code for the GetStarted component.

Here is my code:

```
  export class GetStarted extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      open: false,
      canSubmit: false,
      freelancershow:false,
      ifclient:false,
      type:'',
      phone: "",
      show:true,
      showOtp:false,
      user:{},
      client:{},
      loggedin:'',
      success:false,
      message:'',
      job_types :'',
      rates:'',
      techs:'',
      id:'',
      searchFor:'Freelancers',
      userSearchTerm:'',
      jobSearchTerm: [],
      searchtypes:0,
      freejobSearchTerm:'',
      freeSearchTerm:'',
      company_name:'',
      dataSearch:[],
      getskillarr: [],
      searchString:'',
      domainSearch: [],
      skillArr:[],
      chipData: [],
      chipArr: [],
      searchText: '',
      dataSource: [],
      userName: "",
      admindata: []
    }
    this.styles = {
      chip: {
        margin: 4,
      },
      wrapper: {
        display: 'flex',
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
      },
    };
    this.chipData = this.state.chipData
    const chipToDelete = this.state.chipData.map((chip) => chip.key)
    this.chipData.splice(chipToDelete, 1)
    this.setState({chipData: this.chipData})

    /* dialog actions */
    this.handleDialogClose = this.handleDialogClose.bind(this)
    this.handleDialogOpen = this.handleDialogOpen.bind(this)
    this.handleBackToApp = this.handleBackToApp.bind(this)
    this.handleOpen=this.handleOpen.bind(this)
    this.handleClose=this.handleClose.bind(this)
    this.logout = this.logout.bind(this)
    this.handleSearch = this.handleSearch.bind(this)
    this.handleChange =this.handleChange.bind(this)
    this.getskill = this.getskill.bind(this)
  }

  handleClose() {
    this.setState({open: false});
  }

  onDatesChange({ startDate, endDate }) {
    this.setState({ startDate, endDate })
  }

  onFocusChange(focusedInput) {
    this.setState({ focusedInput })
  }


  componentWillMount() {
    const { dispatch } = this.props
    dispatch(GetBlogs())
    dispatch(GetEvents())
    dispatch(SearchSkills())
   dispatch(GetAllFeaturedUsers())
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {     
     this.setState({ admindata: nextProps.admindata})
    if (nextProps.login.sendOtpResponse && nextProps.login.sendOtpResponse.success === false) {
      this.setState({
        showOtp: false, 
        err: nextProps.login.sendOtpResponse.message 
      })
    } else if (nextProps.login.sendOtpResponse && nextProps.login.sendOtpResponse.success === true) {
      this.setState({
        showOtp: true, 
        phone: nextProps.login.sendOtpResponse.user.profile.phone.mobile
      })
    } else if (nextProps.login.verifyOtpResponse && nextProps.login.verifyOtpResponse.success === false) {
      this.setState({
        err: nextProps.login.verifyOtpResponse.message 
      })    
    } else if (nextProps.login.verifyOtpResponse && nextProps.login.verifyOtpResponse.success === true) {
      this.setState({
        success: nextProps.login.verifyOtpResponse.success,
        open: false,
        type: nextProps.login.verifyOtpResponse.user.type,
        user: nextProps.login.verifyOtpResponse.user,
        userName: nextProps.login.verifyOtpResponse.user.profile.name
     })    
    } else if(nextProps.login.length > 0 && nextProps.login[0].message === 'skills found') {
       let arr = [] 
       for(var i = 0; i < nextProps.login[0].data.length; i++) {
          arr.push(nextProps.login[0].data[i].label)
       }
       this.setState({skillArr:arr})
      } else if(nextProps.login.length > 0 && nextProps.login[0].message === 'searchDomains found') {
          let arr = [] 
      for(var m = 0; m < nextProps.login[0].data.length; m++) {
        arr.push(nextProps.login[0].data[m].name)
      }
      this.setState({ skillArr: arr })
      } else if(nextProps.login.length > 0 && nextProps.login[0].message === 'searchDomains found') {
      let arr = [] 
      for(var n = 0; n < nextProps.login[0].data.length; n++) {
        arr.push(nextProps.login[0].data[n].text)
      }
        this.setState({ skillArr: arr })
    } else if(nextProps.login.length > 0 && nextProps.login[0].data) {
        this.setState({ dataSearch: nextProps.login[0].data })
      } 
      else {
      this.setState({ open: true })
    }
  }

  handleDialogClose() {
    this.setState({ open: false })
  }

  handleDialogOpen() {
    this.setState({ open: true })
  }

  handleOpen() {
    this.setState({ open: true })
  }

  handleBackToApp() {
  }

  change_form(){
    this.setState({ show: !this.state.show })
  }

  logout(){
    if(!this.state.ifclient){
      localStorage.clear(); 
      window.location = "/"
    } else {
      localStorage.clear(); 
      window.location = "/"
    }
  }
getskill(values) {
this.state.getskillarr.indexOf(values) > -1 ? this.state.getskillarr.splice(this.state.getskillarr.indexOf(values), 1) : this.state.getskillarr.push(values)
this.setState({getskillarr: this.state.getskillarr})
this.handleSearch()
}
  handleSearch() {
    var data = this.state
    const { dispatch } = this.props
    if(this.state.searchFor === "job") {
      var newobj = {}
      newobj.searchText = data.getskillarr
      newobj.userSearchTerm = data.userSearchTerm
      newobj.rates = data.rates || 'hourly'
      newobj.type = 'job'
      localStorage.setItem('HomepageSearchData', JSON.stringify(newobj))
    } else {
      var newobj2 = {}
      newobj2.searchText = data.getskillarr
      newobj2.userSearchTerm = data.userSearchTerm
      newobj2.rates = data.rates || 'hourly'
      newobj2.type = 'freelancer'
      localStorage.setItem('HomepageSearchData', JSON.stringify(newobj2))
    }
    const route = '/filter-results'
    browserHistory.push(route)
  }

  handleChange(type,e){
    const state = this.state
    if(type === 'userSearch') {
      state.userSearchTerm = e.target.value
    } else if(type === 'techs') {
      state.jobSearchTerm.push(e.target.value)
    } else if(type !== 'techs') {
      state.domainSearch.push(e.target.value)
    }
    this.setState(state)
  }

  changeUser (value) {
    const state = this.state
    state.searchFor = value
    this.setState(state)
    this.setState({user: value})
  }

  render() {
    var slide = this.state.admindata.length
    var settings = {
      dots: false,
      infinite: true,
      speed: 500,
     slidesToShow:4,
     slidesToScroll:1,

      adaptiveHeight: true,
      responsive: [
        {
          breakpoint: 768,
          settings: {
            arrows: false,
            centerMode: true,
            slidesToShow: 3
          }
        },
        {
          breakpoint: 480,
          settings: {
            arrows: false,
            centerMode: true,
            slidesToShow: 1
          }
        }
      ]
    } 
    var featuredSettings =  {
      dots: false,
      infinite: false,
      speed: 500,
      slidesToShow:4,
      slidesToScroll:1,
      adaptiveHeight: true,
      responsive: [
        {
          breakpoint: 768,
          settings: {
            arrows: false,
            centerMode: true,
            slidesToShow: 3
          }
        },
        {
          breakpoint: 480,
          settings: {
            arrows: false,
            centerMode: true,
            slidesToShow: 1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={muiTheme}>
        <div>     
           { 
    <div className="home-section">
              <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-12 col-xs-12">            

             <div className="new-search">
                <h1 className="f-bold text-blue">Amgigs</h1>
                <p className="sub-head">Find freelancers and contractors online at your timezone and close to your proximity.</p>

                <div className="input-group">
                          <div className="input-group-btn">
                         <IconMenu
                            iconStyle={{color: '#999',padding:'0 important'}}
                            iconButtonElement={<IconButton id="icbtn"><MoreVertIcon /></IconButton>}
                            anchorOrigin={{horizontal: 'left', vertical: 'top'}}
                            targetOrigin={{horizontal: 'left', vertical: 'top'}}
                          >
                            <MenuItem onClick={this.changeUser.bind(this,'freelancer')} primaryText="Find Freelancer" />
                            <MenuItem onClick={this.changeUser.bind(this,'job')} primaryText="Find Job" />

                          </IconMenu>
                      </div>
                 {/* <input type="text" className="form-control" aria-label="..." placeholder="Search"/>*/}

                          <input type="text" className="form-control" aria-label="..." placeholder={this.state.searchFor} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this,'userSearch')} value={this.state.userSearchTerm} />

                          <div className="input-group-btn">
            {/*<button type="button" className="btn btn-primary">Search</button>*/}
            <button type="button" id="homesearchbtn" className="btn btn-lg btn-primary" onClick={this.handleSearch}>Search</button>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                          </div> 
          <div className="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 text-center">
            <div className="category">
                <h4>Search freelancers at any categories</h4>

                {this.state.skillArr.map((skill, i) => {
                  return(
                    <button key={i} className="btn btn-success" onClick={this.getskill.bind(this, skill)}>{skill}</button>
                    )
                })}

               </div>
                    </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> }
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-12">

                {this.state.admindata.length > 0 ?
                  <div>
                  <h3>Featured Freelancers</h3> 
                  <Slider {...featuredSettings}>
                    {this.state.admindata.map(function(data,i){
                      return(<div className="parking-wrapper" key={i}>
                          <div className="parking-inner-container">
                              <div className="parking-inner">
                              <div className="parking-container">
                                <div className="parking-image-wrapper">
                                  <div className="availability-btn">
                                      <Link className="btn btn-primary text-white" target="_blank" to={'http://www.amgigs.com:2368'+data.url}>Chat Now</Link>
                                  </div>
                                      <div className="parking-image-cover"  style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${data.profile.picture})` }}>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        <div className="parking-info">
                            <div className="parking-title">
                                <h1>{data.profile.name}</h1>
                            </div>
                            <div className="parking-location">
                            <h2><EllipsisText text={data.email} length={'50'} /></h2>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                      ) 
                  })
                }
              </Slider>
              </div>
              : "" }
                </div>
            </div>
      </div>




<div className="parking-section">
    <div className="container">
    <div className="row">
      <div className="col-md-5 col-sm-5">
        <div >
          <h2>Hire expert freelancers for your job online</h2>
          <p>Freelancers for thousands of jobs from web design, mobile app development, product design to manufacturing </p>
                  <Link to="/signup" className="btn btn-primary">Get Started with amgigs</Link>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="col-md-7 col-sm-7">
        <img className="img-responsive" src="https://membermouse.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Freelancer-Liability-Featured.png" alt=""/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>


      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
             <div className="col-md-12">
              <h3>Blogs</h3>
              {this.props.blogdata.length > 0 ?
                <Slider {...settings}>
                  {this.props.blogdata.map(function(data,i){
                    return(<div className="parking-wrapper" key={i}>
                  <div className="parking-inner-container">
                      <div className="parking-inner">
                      <div className="parking-container">
                        <div className="parking-image-wrapper">
                          <div className="availability-btn">
                                <Link className="btn btn-primary text-white" target="_blank" to={'http://www.amgigs.com:2368'+data.url}>Read more</Link>
                    </div>
                              <div className="parking-image-cover"  style={{ backgroundImage: `url(http://www.amgigs.com:2368${data.image})` }}>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                <div className="parking-info">
                    <div className="parking-title">
                        <h1>{data.title}</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div className="parking-location">
                        <h2><EllipsisText text={data.markdown} length={'70'} /></h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
                  </div>)
                })
              }
            </Slider>
            : "" }
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>

          <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-12">
              <h3>Events</h3>
              {this.props.eventdata.length > 0 ?
                <Slider {...settings}>
                  {this.props.eventdata.map(function(data,i){
                    return(<div className="parking-wrapper" key={i}>
                  <div className="parking-inner-container">
                      <div className="parking-inner">
                      <div className="parking-container">
                        <div className="parking-image-wrapper">
                          <div className="availability-btn">
                                <Link className="btn btn-primary text-white" target="_blank" to={'http://www.amgigs.com:2369'+data.url}>Read more</Link>
                          </div>
                              <div className="parking-image-cover"  style={{ backgroundImage: `url(http://www.amgigs.com:2369${data.image})` }}>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                <div className="parking-info">
                    <div className="parking-title">
                        <h1>{data.title}</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div className="parking-location">
                        <h2><EllipsisText text={data.markdown} length={'70'} /></h2>
                </div>    
        </div>
                  </div>)
                })
              }
            </Slider>
            : "" }
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


        </div>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    )
  }
}

GetStarted.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node,
  handleSubmit: PropTypes.func, // redux-form
  pristine: PropTypes.bool, // redux-form
  submitting: PropTypes.bool, // redux-form
  dispatch: PropTypes.func, // redux
  handleDialogClose: PropTypes.func, // close dialog
  isSubmitting: PropTypes.bool,
  err: PropTypes.string,
  ifclient: PropTypes.bool,
  showOtp: PropTypes.bool,
  blogdata:PropTypes.array,
  eventdata:PropTypes.array,
  admindata : PropTypes.array,
}

const stateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    login: state.login,
    isSubmitting: state.login.submitting,
    err: state.signup.err,
    Clientid:state.signup.Clientid,
    ifclient:state.ifclient,
    userType:state.signup.userType,
    showOtp:state.showOtp,
    blogdata:state.blogs.data.data ? state.blogs.data.data.posts : [],
    eventdata:state.events.data.data ? state.events.data.data.posts : [],
    admindata : state.admin.data ? state.admin.data.data : []
  }

}
export default connect(stateToProps)(GetStarted)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remove setState calls in the constructor, instead you can initialize the state as you have done for other properties.

"The constructor for a React component is called before it is mounted."
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#constructor